# How to get all Vector layers from OpenLayers map?

Tags: openlayers-2, vector

OpenLayers.Map object exposes a method call getLayersByClass.  How do I use this method to retrieve all of the Vector layers from the map?

I tried map.getLayersByClass("Vector") but this returned an empty array.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The class should be `OpenLayers.Layer.Vector` not `Vector`. So your code should be:

```
map.getLayersByClass("OpenLayers.Layer.Vector")
```

Comment: You're welcome :) Good luck.

Comment: What is the OpenLayers 3 equivalent for this?