# Using layer loadstart & loadend events in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: openlayers, layers, events, loading

OpenLayers 2 has these layer events "loadstart & loadend."

What is equivalent to them in OpenLayers 3?

While a vector layer loads and is rendered, I need to show a loading icon.

Comment: What type of vector source do you use? Can you please provide a bit more context?

Comment: Related question: [Trigger event once layer is loaded](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129658/trigger-event-once-layer-is-loaded)

Answer (score 21):

Assuming you use an `ol.layer.Vector` with an `ol.source.GeoJSON` you can use something like this:

```js
var vectorSource = new ol.source.GeoJSON({
  projection : 'EPSG:3857',
  url: 'http://examples.org/fearures.json'
});

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vectorSource
});

map.addLayer(vectorLayer);

// show loading icon
// ...

var listenerKey = vectorSource.on('change', function(e) {
  if (vectorSource.getState() == 'ready') {
    // hide loading icon
    // ...
    // and unregister the "change" listener 
    ol.Observable.unByKey(listenerKey);
    // or vectorSource.unByKey(listenerKey) if
    // you don't use the current master branch
    // of ol3
  }
});
```

This shows how to get a notification when the vector source is loaded. It only works with sources inheriting from `ol.source.StaticVector`. Examples include `ol.source.GeoJSON` and `ol.source.KML` .

Also, note that this code may no longer work in the future when ol3 will provide a consistent way to know if/when a source is loaded.

Comment: Great! I was looking for this too. Wondering why OL3 does not include it yet.

Comment: Why not `vectorSource.once('change', function(e){...}`?

Answer (score 18):

In ol3 version 3.10.0 things have changed. So is more clear than older versions but still more complicated than ol2.

**So for TILE (ol.layer.Tile) layers your code snip should look like:**

```
//declare the layer
var osmLayer =  new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.OSM()
});
//asign the listeners on the source of tile layer
osmLayer.getSource().on('tileloadstart', function(event) {
//replace with your custom action
document.getElementById('tilesloaderindicatorimg').src = 'css/images/tree_loading.gif';
 });

osmLayer.getSource().on('tileloadend', function(event) {
//replace with your custom action
document.getElementById('tilesloaderindicatorimg').src = 'css/images/ok.png';
 });
osmLayer.getSource().on('tileloaderror', function(event) {
//replace with your custom action        
document.getElementById('tilesloaderindicatorimg').src = 'css/images/no.png';
 });
```

**while for WMS layers the approach is a bit different:**

```
//declare the layer
var wmsLayer =   new ol.layer.Image({
source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
  attributions: [new ol.Attribution({
    html: '&copy; ' +
        '<a href="http://www.geo.admin.ch/internet/geoportal/' +
        'en/home.html">' +
        'National parks / geo.admin.ch</a>'
  })],
  crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
  params: {'LAYERS': 'ch.bafu.schutzgebiete-paerke_nationaler_bedeutung'},
  serverType: 'mapserver',
  url: 'http://wms.geo.admin.ch/'
})
});

//and now asign the listeners on the source of it
var lyrSource = wmsLayer.getSource();
  lyrSource.on('imageloadstart', function(event) {
  console.log('imageloadstart event',event);
  //replace with your custom action
  var elemId = event.target.params_.ELEMENTID;
  document.getElementById(elemId).src = 'css/images/tree_loading.gif'; 
  });

  lyrSource.on('imageloadend', function(event) {
   console.log('imageloadend event',event);
  //replace with your custom action
  var elemId = event.target.params_.ELEMENTID;
  document.getElementById(elemId).src = 'css/images/ok.png'; 
  });

  lyrSource.on('imageloaderror', function(event) {
   console.log('imageloaderror event',event);
  //replace with your custom action
  var elemId = event.target.params_.ELEMENTID;
  document.getElementById(elemId).src = 'css/images/no.png'; 
  });
```

**For WFS Vector layers things are even more complicated:**

```
//declare the vector source
sourceVector = new ol.source.Vector({
    loader: function (extent) {
        //START LOADING
        //place here any actions on start loading layer
        document.getElementById('laodingcont').innerHTML = "<font color='orange'>start loading.....</font>";
        $.ajax('http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs', {
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                service: 'WFS',
                version: '1.1.0',
                request: 'GetFeature',
                typename: 'water_areas',
                srsname: 'EPSG:3857',
                bbox: extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:3857'
            }
        }).done(loadFeatures)
            .fail(function () {
            //FAIL LOADING
            //place here any actions on fail loading layer
            document.getElementById('laodingcont').innerHTML = "<font color='red'>error loading vector layer.</font>";
        });
    },
    strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox
});

//once we have a success responce, we need to parse it and add fetaures on map
function loadFeatures(response) {
formatWFS = new ol.format.WFS(),
sourceVector.addFeatures(formatWFS.readFeatures(response));
 //FINISH LOADING
document.getElementById('laodingcont').innerHTML = "<font color='green'>finish loading vector layer.</font>";
}
```

[check this post. it has all the above +  a fiddle for the WFS vector layers](http://freeopengis.blogspot.gr/2015/09/openlayers-3-load-start-load-end-events.html)

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE! Can you please expand your answer and provide a short synopsis of the article you linked to and what part is relevant to the answer of this question. This way the answer will be able to help people on this site, even after the link dies.

Comment: sorry newby. done!!!!!!!!

Comment: to check which layer type you have, here is how you van do it for OL3 http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/140852/63141

Comment: This should be the top answer!

Comment: Please OL guys.... KISS man...KISS....

Answer (score 2):

I have not found the class `ol.source.GeoJSON`, and could not find a case where `vectorSource.getState() != 'ready'`. So I ended up doing something like this:

```
    function spin(active) {
        if (active) {
            // start spinning the spinner
        } else {
            // stop spinning the spinner
        }
    }

    // Toggle spinner on layer loading
    layer.on('change', function() {
        spin();
    });
    layer.getSource().on('change', function() {
        spin(false);
    });
```

Comment: please also post the spin function, it looks like you are just spinning them and not stopping the spinning on finish loading the layer

Answer (score 1):

you can also use the [getState()](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.source.Vector.html#getState) function

```
if (source instanceof ol.source.Vector) {
        source.on("change", function () {
            //console.log("Vector change, state: " + source.getState());
            switch (source.getState()) {
                case "loading":
                    $("#ajaxSpinnerImage").show();
                    break;
                default:
                    $("#ajaxSpinnerImage").hide();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I am using ol-v4.2.0. `source.getState()` always returns 'ready'

Answer (score 1):

On OL 4.5.0, for vector layers I haven't found a way to deal with the source, instead I use the following on the layer events:

```
if (layer instanceof ol.layer.Vector) {
    layer.on("precompose", function () {
              $("#ajaxSpinnerImage").show();
            });
    layer.on("render", function () {
              $("#ajaxSpinnerImage").hide();
            });
}
```

Hope it can help.