# Logging in Openalyers3

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-2, log

How to use the console.log() on openlayers3 objects?

For example if I log the map object in openlayers2 this is a result. [image: this]

Here i can observe the map, layers, baselayers etc. and its very helpful in development.

But with the new openlayers i.e. openlayers3 when i console log the map object i get something totally different in log. After googling a bit, i found [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/115892/how-to-get-layer-type-in-openlayers-3) post, and tried logging the map object as `map.getLayers()` and i get this output[image]

which doesn't seems helpful compared to older version.
 So is there any way to log the openlayers objects so as to get the log clear as it used to in the version 2+. Any pointers related to this are most welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you're already using the debug.js version, so that's good.  You're not really doing anything wrong or missing anything.

Unfortunately, there were a lot of enhancements in the v3 engine which means you'll have to go digging for the information you want.

For instance, the map projection information is no longer found on the `map` object directly, but within `map.getView()` (*see below*).

Have a look through the API and you will eventually come across the methods / properties that will get the information you need.

API for `Map`: http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.Map.html
API for `View`: http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.View.html

Example of `map.getView()`:

[image: screen]

Good Luck!

Comment: It seems that this is the only way you can work with OL3 as of now.