# How do I get all the Layer Vectors added to a Map in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: openlayers

I had a look at this post: [How to get all Vector layers from OpenLayers map?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/40797/how-to-get-all-vector-layers-from-openlayers-map)

The following construct is shown:

```
    map.getLayersByClass("OpenLayers.Layer.Vector")
```

Unfortunately getLayersByClass is not recognised in this version of OpenLayers.

I add each of my vector layers here:

```
    if (!group.olSourceVector)
            group.olSourceVector = new ol.source.Vector({});

        if (!group.olLayerVector)
            group.olLayerVector = new ol.layer.Vector({ source: group.olSourceVector });

    this.olMap.addLayer(group.olLayerVector);
```

Then features are added to each LayerVector.

Just prior to drawing the map, I want to run through all the Layer Vectors to calculate the extent of the map.

Answer (score 4):

The newer versions of OpenLayers allow you to get all map layers regardless of class name etc. with the [`map.getLayers()` function](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Map-Map.html#getLayers).
 This function returns an ol.Collection object.

Take a look at the answer here, it's an older solution to the same problem as yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30121024/openlayers-3-zoom-to-combined-extent

It's a little outdated now (`map.getView().fitExtent` has been renamed to `.fit` for example) so I've adapted the code for your scenario.

Given that you appear to be using groups, it's also necessary to include a check for whether or not the current layer is actually a group; and if it is, to loop through all sub-layers.

```
//Create an empty extent that we will gradually extend
var extent = ol.extent.createEmpty();

map.getLayers().forEach(function(layer) {
    //If this is actually a group, we need to create an inner loop to go through its individual layers
    if(layer instanceof ol.layer.Group) {
        layer.getLayers().forEach(function(groupLayer) {
            //If this is a vector layer, add it to our extent
            if(layer instanceof ol.layer.Vector)
                ol.extent.extend(extent, groupLayer.getSource().getExtent());
        });
    }
    else if(layer instanceof ol.layer.Vector)
       ol.extent.extend(extent, layer.getSource().getExtent());
});

//Finally fit the map's view to our combined extent
map.getView().fit(extent, map.getSize());
```